# No sound when upgrading to Linux 3.9 Kernel

Tags: sound, kernel, 13.04, headphones

I recently upgraded to the 3.9 Linux Kernel (on Ubuntu 13.04) and lost all sound at first, and then miraculously brought back sound to the speakers (after playing a bit with `alsamixer`, but still no sound when plugging headphones.